# One view for various data from DB using repositories and UoW

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern

I come from PHP and I really struggle with one model/one view approach when trying to display data from multiple entities in one View.

I've been learning asp.net mvc 4 with EF for about a month but still didn't find a good working solution to solve this issue.

My current approach is to access DB through Unit-Of-Work that creates Repository for every entity (table in DB)

```
 public GenericRepository<Domain> DomainRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.domainRepository == null)
            {
                this.domainRepository = new GenericRepository<Domain>(context);
            }
            return domainRepository;
        }
    }
```

then repository holds data from given entity (in this scenario DB),

```
 public GenericRepository(PanelContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TTypeParam>();
    }
```

and uses methods to filter data etc.

Using single repository to serve given view is not a problem because it uses only one model(entity).

When I'm trying to create model class (Combined) that holds ex. two models (Domain and Domain2) it's not a part of given context because that entity doesn't exist so it's pointless to use @model namespace.Models.Combined in a View.

Right now I'm using tuple to pull data from multiple repositories and use it to populate strongly-typed View but I know that there has to be a better way...

Basically the question is how to create an (abstract)? model class (entity)? that will hold data from multiple repositories and serve as viewmodel for a given View?

Big, big thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the view model is not db entity. It's just a bucket used to send data to view. The controller populates that view model taking all the data required from the Model (repositories,services).

So if your view model is the Combined type, the controller will ask the repositories (which are NOT wrappers over EF, forget the examples you saw on asp.net mvc site or ef tutorials, they're wrong and teach you the repository anti-pattern) for data, wich may or may not be in the format neded by the view model. If it isn't, then create some extension methods in which you can map the objects returned by the repos to the view model.

So, the view model serves the View and it's populated by the controller with data from repositories. This way, the View is decoupled from the Model, because it knows only about the view model.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It helped a little bit but my key issue was how to create specific model that will combine multiple data from multiple DB and other sources and use that model to pass data to a view.